# Updating Play Store app by apk failed although same signing key

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-install-apk

I have developed an Android application and I'm now distributing it over the Play Store. Now I have tried to update the application with an apk using adb. I have used the same signing key as for the APK I have released on the Play Store (and I increased the version code by one). I'm getting the following error message:

> adb: failed to install app-v2.1.apk: Failure
> [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package
> com.myapp signatures do not match the
> previously installed version; ignoring!]

Why is this error message although I have used the same signing key? I let Google Play manage my signing key. Is that the problem?

Comment: *I let Google Play manage my signing key. Is that the problem?* **yes** ... in this case google unpack your apk and pack it again **with it's own key** fx to delivery only needed ABI(if you are using native) or only given resources(fx xxdpi, en)

Comment: @Selvin How can I revoke that Google Play is managing my signing key?